# Does it matter if two people are using the same Wordpress admin account?

Tags: wp-admin

Just wanna ask around if its possible for a person to disconnect from wp-admin when someone is already using the same account? Like for example two people are sharing only one wp-admin account. One will disconnect and the other one will not be disconnected. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, It is possible . 
It is also possible to make it impossible .

Comment: Can you explain your answer better? It sounds like a bit of rhyme. :)

Comment: gives me a vertigo. @_@

Comment: Not much to explain . you asked if it is possible for two people to connect simultaneously , and then one of them to disconnect , leaving the other connected . My answer is : yes , it is possible . a deafault install will do just that.

Comment: The other part of the answer was that if someone really wants to , by writing functions/ using plugins/ scripting - one can also make it IMPOSSIBLE for two people to use at the same time the same user account. but your question was only if it is possiable . not how to make it impossible. Nor did you ask about WHY is it happening or the technical details ..

Comment: so its also possible for the database to be overwrited? right?

Comment: what do you mean by overwrite ? every user will write on the DB INDEPENDENTLY. even if for WP - they are the same "user" . so each person will act normally on the DB . unless, by a virtually impossible coincidence, they will both try to write on the same nano-second. :-)

Comment: ok. i really learned a lot from you guys. thanks much. ;)

Comment: like said before , clicking the small "V" sign and accepting would be nice ..